# A unix user seems to be usurping www-data when PHP executes curtain functions

Tags: php, apache, unix, permissions, linode

I'm running a LAMP stack on a linode. The Ubuntu version is Lucid.

When a PHP script executes a `mkdir()` or `move_uploaded_file` command, the newly created folder/file winds up being owned by a unix user 'Grusha'. I did create this user, but it should not be owning files. The web folder overall is owned by `www-data`, as is (by extension) the containing folder inside which the new folder/files are moving.

The user's /etc/passwd line is like this:

```
grusha:x:1000:1003:,,,:/home/grusha:/bin/bash
```

And /etc/group is this:

```
grusha:x:1003:
```

Grusha owns the PHP sessions as they're created too, although nothing else. No processes or files on the system run as Grusha either.

I log in with a public key, and the user who that goes through is not Grusha (nor root).

When I delete Grusha, I can no longer restart Apache. I get `bad username` and the restart fails. My PHP sessions also don't work.

So in the end I add Grusha again and the server will start and everything works except that scripts make files owned by Grusha, not `www-data`.

I've been looking around as much as possible, but can't find any info. My `httpd.conf` is empty. My `apache2.conf` contains these lines:

```
User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}
```

And those variables are defined as `www-data` in `/etc/apache2/envars`.

If anyone has any suggestions I'd be grateful.

Thanks a lot,
Elliot

Comment: Did you just unpack those files from a TAR? Is any process running as Grusha?

Comment: i did not unpack from TAR, BUT:  when I run "top" while i'm logged into the site's backend, every so often Grusha appears.  Like this:

29205 grusha    20   0 52464 8044 3156 S    0  0.8   0:00.03 apache2     

does this help at all??

Comment: i had to be fast to copy that, it comes and goes quickly.

Comment: so the command is "apache2"-- but how, and why?

Answer (score 0):

The suPHP module is probably enabled. Its function is to let PHP code execute under the user ID of the user who owns the scripts, instead of `www-data`, which can be very insecure on a shared server. Try turning off suPHP by deleting `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/suphp.load` and `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/suphp.conf`.

On the off chance that's not the problem, check that the user `grusha` doesn't actually have the same numeric user ID as `www-data` (in `/etc/passwd`). That's probably unlikely though.

Comment: Thanks for writing, but these solutions won't work.

- Those mod files aren't present in the mods-enabled directory.
- www-data is defined as user and group in /etc/apache2/envvars
- and the user IDs aren't the same.  The two lines from /etc/passwd:
  grusha:x:1000:1003:,,,:/home/grusha:/bin/bash  AND
  www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/bin/sh

Thanks again though.

Comment: Well, I don't know anything about [linode](http://www.linode.com/) but maybe they have some other configuration that causes suPHP to be enabled. `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled` is used by Debian and others, but maybe linode uses some other convention. If still no help, then I hope that somebody else will have another idea.

Comment: Been reading about suPHP-- it does seem a likely culprit. But t's not there. And Grusha doens't own anything in the site structure, so maybe suPHP's not to blame. Anyway it was a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, this is solved.  Apologies.
I had mpm directives in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ that caused apache to run as grusha.
Unsure how that happened, but it's fixed in any case. 
Thanks to you both for thinking about my problem.